# Method find_by_user_id_and_friend_id does not seem to work - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> i am unsure why the method
>   `Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)` &
>   `Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(friend, user)` gives a nil,
>   could one kindly explain this to me
>
> why does the method `Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user,
>   friend)` give a nil and the method
>   `Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user.id, friend.id)` does
>   not? basically could one explain the difference to me

```
2.3.0 :065 >   user
 => #<User id: 1, email: "richill@gmail.com", created_at: "2016-11-22 15:56:19", updated_at: "2016-12-06 11:39:29", firstname: "richill", lastname: "artloe">

2.3.0 :068 >   friend
 => #<User id: 2, email: "emma@gmail.com", created_at: "2016-11-22 16:19:25", updated_at: "2016-11-22 16:19:25", firstname: "emma", lastname: "watson"> 

Friendship.create(user: user, friend: friend, status: 'pending')
Friendship.create(user: friend, friend: user, status: 'requested')

2.3.0 :078 >   Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)
  Friendship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ? AND "friendships"."friend_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", nil], ["friend_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil 
2.3.0 :079 > 

2.3.0 :079 > Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(friend, user)
  Friendship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ? AND "friendships"."friend_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", nil], ["friend_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil 
2.3.0 :080 >
```

i believe i am suppose to get something like the below results:

```
>> Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)
=> #<Friendship:0x2bf74ec @attributes={"status"=>"pending", "accepted_at"=>nil,
"id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1", "position"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2007-01-03 18:34:09",
 "friend_id"=>"1198"}>

>> Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(friend, user)
=> #<Friendship:0x490a7a0 @attributes={"status"=>"requested", "accepted_at"=>nil
, "id"=>"2", "user_id"=>"1198", "position"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2007-01-03 18:34
:20", "friend_id"=>"1"}>
```

very strange. it works when placed like this

```
Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user.id, friend.id)
=> #<Friendship id: 1, user_id: 1, friend_id: 2, status: "pending", created_at: "2016-12-06 11:55:06", updated_at: "2016-12-06 11:55:06">
```

but does not work when placed like this:

```
Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)
=> nil
```

> could one explain why this is to me

what is the difference

```
2.3.0 :016 >   Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)
  Friendship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ? AND "friendships"."friend_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", nil], ["friend_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil 
2.3.0 :017 > Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user.id, friend.id)
  Friendship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ? AND "friendships"."friend_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["friend_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Friendship id: 1, user_id: 1, friend_id: 2, status: "pending", created_at: "2016-12-06 11:55:06", updated_at: "2016-12-06 11:55:06"> 
2.3.0 :018 >
```

Comment: try passing in `user.id` and `friend.id` though I don't think that'd make a difference.  Also use `create!` if you're in the console so that you'll get an exemption if the friendship isn't created.  Also refrain from these dynamic methods.  Start using `find_by(user_id: user.id, friend_id: friend.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the find_by_id method is the same as using the where method except it only returns the first record that is found. ([See the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ac027338e4a165273607dccee49a3d38bc836794/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L77))

Since the method is searching for id's I believe you need to pass the id directly rather than the instance of your object for it to work. This is the same when you use the .find method.